# With HTML select dropdowns, is there a way to have some text as the option, but a corresponding text to show as selected?

Tags: html, html-select

Basically, I was wondering if it was possible to have an abbreviated text show that corresponds to the selected option. For example, with this dropdown:

```
<select>
    <option value="monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
</select>
```

Upon selecting "Monday", the user would typically see the dropdown like this:

```
____________
|Monday | ⮟|
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

But I would like the user to see it like this:

```
_______
|M | ⮟|
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

This is because I don't have enough space for a large dropdown in that area of my page.
I still need the dropdown list to be full words though, in order for it to be understandable. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can just set a width on the select element, then it will just show as much as possible.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. Out of curiosity though, what if I needed to have a different word?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.